# Supporting IPv6 on iOS App (Keep getting rejected although it works in tests)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipv6

I am trying for quite some time to deploy an app but it keeps getting rejected as it doesn't work on Apple's IPv6 only network, even though I am using NSURLSession to send a POST. I have made more attempts than I can count and ran out of options, does anyone know if it is a problem related to their testing environment or it is to my code?
Here it is the code:

```
    - (NSData *) postToServer: (NSData *) msg {

        __block NSData *urlData = NULL;
        self.status = @"offline";
        dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

        NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver.php"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setHTTPBody:msg];

        NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

            if (error) {
                self.status = @"offline";
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
                return;
            }

            if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {

                NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];

                if (statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300) {

                    self.status = @"online";
                    urlData = data;

                }
                else {

                    self.status = @"offline";

                }
                NSLog(@"Código resposta: %ld / Resposta ==> %@", (long)statusCode, [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
            }
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);

        }];
        [postDataTask resume];

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

        return urlData;

    }
```

Please, if I have made anything wrong on this help me fix it, this is delaying my work schedule so much and I could not figure it out even reading all Apple forum's threads about IPv6. (This code works at my workplace for iPhone SE iOS 9.3.2, only fails at the review).
Thanks for the help.
Natan

Comment: Are you testing on an IPv6-only network?

Comment: What is the EXACT reason Apple has given you for rejecting the app?

Comment: "We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad and iPhone running iOS 9.3.2 on Wi-Fi.

Specifically, we could not access the contents of your app due to an alert displayed on login."

Comment: The reason is that basically my app does not access the internet while on IPv6 only network and I could not figure out why, since I used Apple's recommended methods

Comment: That's not what the reason said :S It says there is a popup on the screen that they cannot dismiss upon launch. You are also making a SYNCHRONOUS networking call. It could take forever to complete and Apple doesn't have to patience to deal with that. The code you have above is not showing the alert that Apple is talking about.

Comment: The alert is dismissable and says "The first login must be online", which only appears when the device is not connected to the internet (it is shown in another piece of code, irrelevant for the error). The rest of the app is only accessible if the login process is successful, so that is why they could not access the contents. And about the call, it is synchronous, but has timeout of 10s so it wont take forever.

Comment: Did you test your app on the NAT64 internet sharing network created from a Mac? That's what you need to test your app on.

Comment: My workplace does not have thunderbolt ethernet, so I could not run this kind of test. I realize this is important, but since it is out of my reach I wanted to check if you guys can spot any mistakes regarding the code. This is the only part that accesses internet, it works on IPv4 and I have tried all the possibilities that should support IPv6 (AFNetworking 3.0, then NSURLConnection, then NSURLSession...).

Comment: @GabrielNatan: You mean you cannot connect a Mac to Ethernet?

Comment: UPDATE: The problem was my server, not my code. It had an IPv6 address, but could not send responses through it. After fixing that, the app was set 'ready for sale'. Thanks for your help, guys!

Comment: @GabrielNatan you shouldn't edit your question to show that it's solved, if you had a solution, post an answer and accept it

Comment: @Jeeter I did not know that, thanks for the info, I accepted your answer below.

Comment: @Gabriel Natan I am also facing the same issue. I am running my app on IPv6 network. It gives error "A server with the specified hostname could not be found". Works perfect on IPv4 network. how to synthesize an IPv4 address while on IPv6 only network and communicate. Please suggest me

Comment: @VJVJ According to Apple, it is recommended that you use high-level networking APIs, for example NSURLSession (for more recent iOS) or NSURLConnection (for compatibility - I have heard that it was deprecated but I cannot say for sure). Using one of these APIs the translation process is done automaticaly, as stated by https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1 (figure 10-3).

Comment: @VJVJ Your case could be similar to mine, have you checked if your server supports IPv6 in the link provided below? If on http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php your result is "green - red - red" the fix for it should be on the server side (although apple says it is not needed, this case is a little different, for more details we can talk through private message or similar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by OP for his solution:

> The problem was my server, which was not ready entirely ready for IPv6. If it had no IPv6 address, the app could synthetize an IPv4 addr while on IPv6 only network and communicate normally, but my host had the address but could not respond through it. If anyone else is having issues with this, try using this test: http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php and check if your host passes AAAA DNS record, but fails the rest, that being the case you should take a look at your server first, not the code (assuming your code is all right, NSURLSession and stuff.

Comment: how to synthesize an IPv4 address while on IPv6 only network and communicate.